# How to debug Hyper-V replication issues

Tags: windows, hyper-v, replication

We are hosting some VMs that are virtualized with Hyper-V. For these we have set up replication which works fine in the beginning but starts to fail pretty soon.

The error it shows when looking at the replication status is:
"Last successful replication for virtual machine 'xxx' has been delayed. Delay has exceeded the defined critical limit. Replication might be encountering problems."

We are also not able to enable replication via the Hyper-V-Manager GUI. When trying to configure, the GUI just flashes endlessly when it checks the configuration after entering the replication server. Configuring replication via Powershell works just fine. Even the initial replication can be executed properly. From then on we are not sure when it fails but it has to happen after a few hours, maximum in a day.

Unfortunately the Event-Log does not help. There are just a few errors and these are only connected to the issues we have when using the GUI. Other than generic information they don't seem to give any hint.

So our question is how to further debug this issues and/or if someone had similar issues and how they can be resolved?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which event logs you read?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, it's a performance problem.
Whenever I had that problem, too much data needed to be replicated to succeed in the time interval until the next replication took place. That was because I did not exclude the pagefile from replication and it was used heavily.
Look at the replication statistics to get an idea about the amount of data.

You could do as I and move the pagefile to a different drive that you don't replicate for a test.

Why it doesn't behave using the GUI, I don't know.